# makefile how to turn this into a macro

Tags: c++, makefile

In trying to write a non-recursive make, I have the following block:

```
dir := $(ROOT)/libs/libA/
include $(dir)/rules.mk

dir := $(ROOT)/libs/libB/
include $(dir)/rules.mk

dir := $(ROOT)/libs/libC/
include $(dir)/rules.mk
```

This is obviously unnecessary repetitive. How can I write a macro to collapse that all so that I just have to provide `libA`, `libB`, and `libC`? I need to also set `dir` before each `include`.

Comment: I asked you in another post, to read the paper .  http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html  It will answer many if not all of your issues.  It is a good paper.  I have successfully implemented and extended the ideas from this paper on multiple occasions.  It works.  Have you read it and found it to be insufficient?

Comment: @MarkGaleck - I have read it several times and am building something based on it... this is the format that one takes. I just want to simplify this part, which that one does not do.

Comment: OK I understand.  IMHO, you will probably find out, that you can't simplify that paper, because eventually you will need all elements from it, if you are building a large system.  So you might as well implement it all from the start.  For example, there is a "directory stack" there.  You may not need it now, but you will need it, if you want to do recursive inclusion.  And of course you will need recursive inclusion.  You can't get away with one level, just like you can't get away with a filesystem with one level of directories.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Dude chill out, I'm still trying to get your answer to work. If/when I can get it to work, I'll accept it.

Comment: never mind I deleted the comment.  no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to include a `rules.mk` makefile inside each of the list of subdirectories, in order, and make the variable `DIR` to be equal to the subdirectory, inside each `rules.mk`.  I use the variable name `DIR`, not `dir` as you wanted, because I believe "global" variables names in makefiles should be uppercase.

For other implementation details of non-recursive makefiles, please consult

evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

```
# include the makefile $2/rules.mk
# and make the variable $1 be equal to the directory $2, inside that makefile
define INCLUDE_DIR
$1 := $2
include $$($1)/rules.mk
endef

# do INCLUDE_DIR for directory variable name $1 and directories $2
define INCLUDE_DIRS
$(foreach dir, $2, $(eval $(call INCLUDE_DIR,$1, $(dir))))
endef


DIRS := \
    $(ROOT)/libs/libA \
    $(ROOT)/libs/libB \


$(call INCLUDE_DIRS,DIR, $(DIRS))
```

Comment: Why just `$(call INCLUDE_DIRS,DIR,$(DIRS))` instead of `$(eval $(call INCLUDE_DIRS,DIR,$(DIRS)))`?

Comment: @Barry because, the first two paragraphs of the code, are for you, the "administrator", somebody knowledgeable about makefiles who typically edits system-level files.  The bottom two, are put in your individual recursive makefile fragment, and are edited by that fragment maintainer, typically a person who wants to have everything as simple as possible.  So for their benefit, there is a simple function call, so they don't have to know anything about `eval` and such things.

Comment: @Barry  With the above setup, it is not needed to call `eval` second time.  That is the benefit for your "user" who wants to have everything simple.  I am not going to explain why it is not needed :)  (following "teach a man to fish") :)

Comment: When I'm recursively including files using this function, make just hangs. Works fine with just the dir:=/include pairs.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I want to spend any more time on this... I don't think non-recursive is worth it. Sure, I can get it to compile a bit faster but I clearly do not understand what I'm doing here and it's not worth the headache. Thanks for the help, I'm just going to assume your answer is correct and move on.

Comment: @Barry well, I did not say my answer works for recursive inclusion case.  For that, you have to have a directory "stack" implemented.  In any case, recursive make simply does not work (with one exception which I am listing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065734/makefile-enforce-library-dependency-ordering/26066761#26066761).  As Obama would put it "Period. Full stop." :)  Yes it is a "headache" to do non-recursive.  But that is how Make is designed to work and there is no alternative.

Comment: @Barry your system may not be big enough to justify the headache.  In that case, simply do not use include at all, just have one big Makefile.  It is perfectly fine.  The only drawback, is that, well, it is a BIG file and one BIG file may be hard to read and maintain.  If that becomes too BIG, that is a sign, you need to split your big Makefile.  To do that, use `include` any way you see fit.  Just get it to work any way you can.  Do not use recursive calls. Period. Full stop.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LIBS := libA libB libC

include $(patsubst %, $(ROOT)/libs/%/rules.mk, $(LIBS))
```

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, I need to also set `dir` before each include. How can I do that? I've edited my question.

Comment: @Barry: Sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Beta well the reason why he is asking this, is because he needs it.  When doing non-recursive make, you have to have a variable that is equal to the "current directory" in each directory makefile fragment.  When you have a directory stack implemented, this variable values are on a stack, each time you include a makefile, the new value is put on a stack, when you end parsing that makefile, off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use GNU make, the following should work:

```
get_mk := $(ROOT)/libs/$(1)/rules.mk

include $(call get_mk,libA)
include $(call get_mk,libB)
include $(call get_mk,libC)
```

You can get more info on `call` at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, I need to also set dir before each include. How can I do that? I've edited my question.

Comment: @Barry, you can use the answer from the other post to have one `include` line instead of three. However, I don't see how you can avoid having to set `dir` three times.