# Docker with make: build image on Dockerfile change

Tags: makefile, docker

I playing with Docker and make utility and try to write rule which rebuilds docker image only on Dockerfile change.
My project structure looks like:

```
 tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
└── project
    └── 1.js
```

My Dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
VOLUME ["/project"]
ENTRYPOINT ["cat"]
CMD ["project/1.js"]
```

It just creates simple ubuntu image with nodejs installation and run a script from shared directory.

Now I want to run this image from Makefile. When I change a Dockerfile I want to rebuild the image.
Makefile looks like:

```
default: run 

run: build
        docker run -v $(CURDIR)/project:/project app-server 

build: Dockerfile
        docker build -t app-server .
```

Now when I execute `sudo make` command it rebuild an image every time.

How can I force make to execute build task only when Dockerfile changed?

Comment: You should really have a look at https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: You probably don't need to do this.  `docker build` internally manages this type of dependency change to have basically the same effect that you are trying to achieve with `make`.  If you don't need to see the status, you can use the `--quiet` option along with `>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you write:

```
run: build
        docker run -v $(CURDIR)/project:/project app-server
```

in a makefile make expects that that recipe will create a file by the name of `run`. make will then check that file's timestamp against the timestamp of its prerequisite files to determine if the recipe needs to be run the next time.

Similarly with the `build` target you have in your makefile.

```
build: Dockerfile
        docker build -t app-server .
```

Neither of those recipes create files with the name of the target however. This means that make cannot use the timestamp of that file to determine whether it needs to re-run the recipe. As such make has to assume that it needs to re-run the recipe (because assuming otherwise would mean the rule would never run).

If you run `make -rRd` you will see what make thinks is going on and you should see indication of what I've just said.

The solution to your problem, therefore, is to create stamp files in each of those targets.

Simply adding `touch $@` (optionally prefixed with `@` to silence the default make echoing of commands it runs) to each of those targets should be enough to get this to work for you.

That being said it might make sense to put `sudo` on each of the recipe lines that need it instead of running `make` with `sudo` if you don't want the stamp files to be owned as root as well.

For the record this is discussed in the GNU Make Manual as section [`4.8 Empty Target Files to Record Events`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets).

Answer (score 8):

Your "targets" `default` `run` and `build` are "phony" targets.  That is an abstract concept, not a real file.  Such phony targets, should not have a recipe (because you can't make them).  They should instead depend on real files, or perhaps other phony targets, and so on, but everything must eventually depend on real files only.

Your phony targets should be marked as such

```
.PHONY: default run build
```

The real targets, on the other hand, should have a recipe - the recipe makes that target.

So, first depend your phony targets, without a recipe, on a real target(s).

Then have real targets have recipes.

I have posted some guidelines at
[makefile enforce library dependency ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065734/makefile-enforce-library-dependency-ordering/26066761#26066761)

Comment: While correct and useful this fails, in the strictest sense only, to answer the question asked because it doesn't help the OP figure out how to get a file to consider the "real file" of the docker run targets. (I'm assuming, of course, that docker doesn't itself just create a file that can be depended on directly.)

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, I often don't answer the question as posed, because I think arrogantly :) that it is better to answer a different question.  Guity as charged Etan!