# Make always build even when there is no file change

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a simple Makefile:

```
all: image 

image: ./common ./source
    docker build -t some-resource -f source/Dockerfile .

.PHONY: all image
```

I expect that `image` is only built when files under folders `common` or `source` have changes. But when I run `make`, it always run `docker run` even without any file change. What's the problem?

Comment: What does the `docker` command actually produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run make, it will try to make the first target, which is `all`. This causes make to make the target `image`. Because there is no actual file named `image` (you even told make that it is a *phony* target), it will always execute the `docker` command.

In this case, it is not possible for make to determine that "common and source have changes". Normally make does this by comparing the modification timestamps of the target and the dependencies but there is no actual target to check (`image` is not a file).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26121279/6783775) with a possible workaround/solution.