# Understanding Makefile with .c=.o and $<

Tags: c, makefile

This is my first Makefile, and I can't figure out some of the syntax used. The questions are marked below:

```
C := gcc

CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -std=

PROG := program_1\
    program_2\
    program_3

SRCS := program_1.c \
    program_2.c \
    program_3.c

OBJS := ${SRCS:.c=.o} 

all: ${OBJS}
  ${CC} ${OBJS} -o ${PROG}

clean:
    rm -f ${PROG} ${OBJS}


.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

1. What does `.c=.o` mean? in
   `OBJS := ${SRCS:.c=.o}`
2. Not sure what `$<` means here, and `.c.o`?

   `.c.o: ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, your `Makefile` has a bug, it does not make the intended targets.  Did you try it?

Second, it is not well written; not following best current practices.

So I will first show you the better version of your Makefile, both correct, as well as written with the best practices:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -std=

SRCS := program_1.c \
    program_2.c \
    program_3.c

OBJS := ${SRCS:c=o} 
PROGS := ${SRCS:.c=}

.PHONY: all
all: ${PROGS}

${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile
    ${CC} $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f ${PROGS} ${OBJS}

%.o: %.c Makefile
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

Now, the answers to your questions are:

`${SRCS:.c=.o}` means, take the variable value `${SRCS}`, which is a string composed of words separated by spaces, and for each word, replace the suffix `.c` with `.o`  .  I dropped `.` in my code because it is not needed and it is common to replace only suffixes after the dot.

This syntax is similar to bash string suffix replacement (for one word) if you are familiar with that.

`$<` when used in the "recipe", means "the first prerequisite" - the first thing after the `:` in the line above.

and the last question is no longer relevant:  `.o.c` syntax is obsolete and not recommended currently.

Please take a look at my "10 Commandments" - my answer at this post:

[makefile enforce library dependency ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065734/makefile-enforce-library-dependency-ordering/26066761#26066761)

, they will give you an idea about the best practices.  Then you can also read up in the GNU Make manual, about the terms above in quotes, that I did not explain here.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was just following a sample makefile given to me at work. Which lines in your Makefile, makes sure that for example program_1.o is linked from program_1.c and that it will generate a target program_1 ?

Comment: @user3630406 these are the "pattern" rules, with `%` in them.  `%` is like a wildcard `*` in shell.  All `%` in the rule have to match the same string, of course.  The first rule, tries to do this matching among the words in `${PROGS}`.  The second, does not have such a constraint, it tries to match anything that has not been matched elsewhere.  I am purposely not giving you all the details, so you have to go and read up :)  Please do not be offended.

Comment: haha.What you have told me so far has been quite helpful.Thanks again!

Comment: Just one more question . I see you placed %.o: %.c Makefile, why did you put Makefile as the prereq, I am looking at other online sources and it seems like %.o : %.c is sufficient ?

Comment: @user3630406  well, the correct way to think of "prerequisites" is, list all the files, that if they change, the resulting target, may change as well.  So, if the Makefile changes, it could be that the recipe for this target changed, in which case, the resulting target might change as well.  So it is good practice to list all included makefiles, on all prerequisite lines.

Comment: I removed the %/o :%/c Makefile line and just added CFLAGS to the recipe in ${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile, and it worked ? I am confused now O_O

Comment: Shuldn't clean be .PHONY as well?

Comment: @user3630406 yes because if you remove `%.o: %.c` rule then Make has a default rule, which "works" but is not exactly the same as what I wrote.  In my opinion, one should not rely on default rules.

Comment: @Anže yes it should

Comment: I would like to ask about line `${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile`, what do the two colons do? I tested it and I guess the middle part matches every name in `PROGS` but I couldn't find online how this structure is called. Could you please explain it a bit or point me to documentation?

Comment: So now, what is the difference between bar := $(foo:%.o=%.c) and bar := $(var:.o=.c)? If there is some difference between the two, can it be explained with an example please?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify exactly which variant of `make` you're using -- there are many.  I'm going to assume you are using GNU make, the most widely used variant.

In GNU make, `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` is a [substitution reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs), and it means "the value of the `SRCS` variable, where `.c` is replaced by `.o` when it appears at the end of a word."  In your example, `SRCS` has the value `program_1.c program_2.c program_3.c`, so `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` means `program_1.o program_2.o program_3.o`.

The `.c.o` is an example of what's known an [old-fashioned *suffix rule*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules).  It tells GNU make "here's how to build a .o file from a .c file with the same name."  The modern equivalent is a *pattern rule* which would look the same except to use `%.o: %.c` in place of `.c.o`.

Finally, `$<` is an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which means "the name of the first prerequisite".

Comment: @EtanReisner `$<` is not used everywhere "in rules", but only "in recipes".  And, it is used and useful in all rules, not just suffix and pattern rules.

Comment: @EricMelski Eric I will respectfully disagree with your answer. `.c=.o` _does not_ mean "characters `.c` substituted with `.o`"

Comment: I second the disagreement about the substitution reference. It does do that but the details are more specific than that. Though I doubt very much that Eric was unaware of that.

Comment: @EtanReisner well, rule has two parts:  the declaration of targets and prerequisites, and below that, the recipe.  So recipe is part proper of rule.

Comment: Sorry guys I am in self-conceited mode today :)  I have just been told, auditioning in my second profession (unrelated to programming), that i'm "very talented".  Sorry for unrelated bragging :)  I just want to explain why I am so strict today.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh I have no doubt that Eric was aware.  It is so obvious to him that he obviously forgot.  No sarcasm intended.  I hold Eric in very high regard :)  But for community's sake, it is good to straighten out, for those newbies who are reading this and may not be aware.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Indeed. Extra clarity is never a bad thing especially in an area as misunderstood and misused as makefiles. I certainly didn't feel attacked in an unreasonable way.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes it amazes me to no end. I mean, the manual for GNU Make is like 100 pages only, and really, compared to other languages, this is very simple stuff. Yet most programmers very proficient in other areas, are totally confused by it.  That's why I am a consultant in this area, it is a niche - many companies have hundreds of very skilled engineers, and nobody knows how to write a decent build system.