# Generate executable file with makefile in linux

Tags: c, makefile, executable

I want to generate two executable file from two sources.

What should i put in the Flag EXEC ?
Is this line correct? --> `EXEC := amqp_consommateur amqp_producteur`

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp/dlo -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq 
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS := -L. -lrabbitmq
SRCS_RAW := amqp_consommateur.c amqp_producteur.c

SRCS := $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW))
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW:.c=.o))
EXEC := amqp_consommateur amqp_producteur

$(info DEBUG: SRCS=$(SRCS))
$(info DEBUG: OBJS=$(OBJS))
$(info DEBUG: EXEC=$(EXEC))

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

#rule to create object directory if it doesnt exist
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

#define implicit rule to build objects in their own directory
#(note -- order only dependency on object directory)
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~  $(EXEC)
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: Have you considered trying it, and seeing what happens?

Comment: `-o $(EXEC)` won't work. You can't output multiple executables with a single compilation.

Comment: @Barmar 12: so you should do two makefiles to generate two executables?

Comment: No, separate rules in the same makefile for each executable.

Comment: This thread might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133377/understanding-makefile-with-c-o-and

Comment: @Barmar: how can I separate rules for each executable ? Thanks.

Comment: There's a built-in default recipe for creating XXX from XXX.o. Just use that instead of writing your own.

Comment: @Barmar: where can i find the default recipe please ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: @zois :Thanks , i will view it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile to compile multiple C programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950395/makefile-to-compile-multiple-c-programs)