# What does this line "${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile" mean in this makefile recipe

Tags: makefile

I am new to makefiles and I was searching the web trying to learn and then I found this makefile from here: [Understanding Makefile with .c=.o and $<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133377/understanding-makefile-with-c-o-and)

Can some one explain to me what this first line means:

```
${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile
    ${CC} $< -o $@
```

Full code:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -std=

SRCS := program_1.c \
    program_2.c \
    program_3.c

OBJS := ${SRCS:c=o} 
PROGS := ${SRCS:.c=}

.PHONY: all
all: ${PROGS}

${PROGS} : % : %.o Makefile
    ${CC} $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f ${PROGS} ${OBJS}

%.o: %.c Makefile
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

Comment: Please see ["Syntax of Static Pattern Rules"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Static-Pattern-Rules).

Comment: And note that static (and non-static) pattern rules are an extension provided only by GNU `make`.  This is not a part of standard makefile syntax, and though GNU `make` is great and widely used, it is by no means the *only* `make` in use.