# Makefile operations for each target

Tags: python, c++, makefile, swig

I want to write a makefile to process multiple targets with same operations. For example, for one target called "quick_sort", my makefile starts as follows:

```
TARGET     = trapz
WRAPPER    = $(TARGET)_wrap.cxx
SRC        = $(TARGET).cc
MATRIXOBJ  = vector.o vector_wrap.o matrix.o matrix_wrap.o matrix3d.o matrix3d_wrap.o
OBJ        = $(SRC:.cc=.o) $(WRAPPER:.cxx=.o) $(MATRIXOBJ)
CXX        = g++
CXXFLAGS   = -O3 -fPIC
INTERFACE  = $(TARGET).i
SWIGOPT    =
SWIG       = swig
PYLIB      = -I/usr/include/python2.7

SO         = so

python_cpp: $(TARGET).i
            $(SWIG) -c++ -python $(INTERFACE)
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SRC)
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(WRAPPER) $(PYLIB)
            $(CXX) -shared $(OBJ) -o _$(TARGET).$(SO)

python_clean:
        rm -f *_wrap* *.o *~ *$(SO) mypython *.pyc .~* core
```

But if I want to add multiple targets:

```
TARGET     = quick_sort bubble_sort standard_sort
WRAPPER    = $(TARGET)_wrap.cxx
SRC        = $(TARGET).cc
MATRIXOBJ  = vector.o vector_wrap.o matrix.o matrix_wrap.o matrix3d.o matrix3d_wrap.o
OBJ        = $(SRC:.cc=.o) $(WRAPPER:.cxx=.o) $(MATRIXOBJ)
```

It doesn't work. How can I generate all my executables without creating makefiles for each of my targets?

Comment: In StackOverflow, if you want the answer, you must show what you tried.  How do you attempt to "generate my executables"? How do you do it for one target?

Comment: @MarkGaleck edited as suggested.

Comment: I see, I answered based on what I guessed at the time.  Let me amend according to what you want.  One thing you should understand right away, is that you should have a separate rule for each file you are writing during the course of the build.  So, instead of one big rule, split it into small rules, one for each file you write.

Comment: I tried, not tested yet, but please remind me, what file is produced by the command `$(SWIG) -c++ -python $(INTERFACE)`

Comment: Oh I remember now, the wrapper is produced by that.  OK let me amend.

Comment: A generic answer: to specify one rule for building arbitrarily many different files, the mechanism you use is the [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
TARGET     := quick_sort bubble_sort standard_sort
MATRIXOBJ  := vector.o vector_wrap.o matrix.o matrix_wrap.o matrix3d.o matrix3d_wrap.o
CXX        := g++
CXXFLAGS   := -O3 -fPIC


.PHONY: all $(TARGET)
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): %: _%.so

_%.so: %_wrap.o %.o $(MATRIXOBJ) Makefile
    $(CXX) -shared $(filter %.o, $^) -o $@

%_wrap.cxx: %.i Makefile
    swig -c++ -python $<

%.o: %.cxx Makefile
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -I/usr/include/python2.7

%.o: %.cc Makefile
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

I added some good practices here.  If you want a summary of good practices, read the "Ten Commandments" in my answer here: [makefile enforce library dependency ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065734/makefile-enforce-library-dependency-ordering/26066761#26066761)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't actually build

Comment: @EmreTurkoz it does for me.  What is the problem?  Please be more specific.  "It does not work" is considered a very bad phrase on Stack Overflow.