# Makefile to auto compile, assemble and link many files in a directory

Tags: shell, gcc, makefile

Sorry for repetition, but I could not find the solution.
Following is the sequence of the commands I want Makefile to accomplish.

```
gcc-elf-gcc -S -combine loadStoreByte.c string.c lib_uart.c bubble_uart.c -o bubble_uart.s 

gcc-elf-as -o startup.o startup.s;
gcc-elf-as -o handler.o handler.s;
gcc-elf-as -o bubble_uart.o bubble_uart.s;

gcc-elf-ld -o bubble_uart -T browtb.x bubble_uart.o startup.o handler.o;
```

That is, I want to compile all C files into a single S file and then assemeble all s files into corresponding object files and the link all object files into one executable.

**I tried the following makefile. The individual targets work fine, but could not run all the target at the same time using "make all".
Please guide how to fix it.**

```
CC = brownie32-elf-gcc
AS = brownie32-elf-as
LK = brownie32-elf-ld
SFILE = $(wildcard *.s)
OFILE = $(patsubst %.s,%,$(SFILE))
CFILE = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(wildcard *.o)

APP = bubble_uart

all: compile assemble link

link: $(OBJ)
        $(LK) -o $(APP) -T browtb.x $^

assemble: $(OFILE)

%: %.s compile
        $(AS) -o $@.o $<

compile: $(CFILE)
        $(CC) -S -combine $^ -o $(APP).s

clean: 
        rm -f $(OBJ) $(APP) $(APP).s *.o
```

Thanks

Comment: I corrected your question, I think it has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile is not written with "best practices" and because of that it was easy for you to make mistakes.  I will re-write your makefile here, with best practices, which solves all your problems.  Please study it with the aid of the GNU Make manual.

The biggest single problem is that you have "procedures/actions", such as "assemble" as make targets.  This makes the makefile into a kind of "procedural" program.  GNU Make is not designed to be a procedural language, instead, it is a declarative language.  The "targets" should not be actions, but actual files, or "phony" files, which should be collections of actual files.

The use of `wildcard` in makefiles is a bad idea - it is best to list your files explicitly, as I have shown.

Please consult my answer 
[makefile enforce library dependency ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065734/makefile-enforce-library-dependency-ordering/26066761#26066761)
for a discussion of good practices, including phony and real targets.

```
MAKEFILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

CFILES := \
    loadStoreByte.c \
    string.c \
    lib_uart.c \
    bubble_uart.c

SFILE_OUTPUT := bubble_uart.s

SFILES := $(SFILE_OUTPUT) \
    startup.s \
    handler.s

OFILES := $(SFILES:s=o)

APP := bubble_uart

.PHONY: all
all: $(APP)

$(APP): browtb.x $(OFILES) $(MAKEFILE)
    gcc-elf-ld -o $@ -T $< $(OFILES)

$(OFILES): %o : %s $(MAKEFILE)
    gcc-elf-as -o $@ $<

$(SFILE_OUTPUT): $(CFILES) $(MAKEFILE)
    gcc-elf-gcc -S -combine $(CFILES) -o $@
```

Comment: thanks @Mark Galeck for the explanation, but the list of c files is not fixed. it may be any number of c files

Comment: @Sajjad yes I know, does not matter - you should always have a list and not use `wildcard`.  If all the c files are sources, you list them.  When you add a new source, you update the list.  If some of c files are not sources, but are generated during the build, you compute the list - like I did above for `SFILES`.

Comment: Speaking of best practises: Defining Makefile variables empty in one line, and then adding to them with one `VAR += foo.c` line per `foo.c` to add is much more convenient than messing with backslashed lines in diffs and merges.

Comment: @ndim I disagree that it is better practice, and I even disagree that it is more convenient.  And, by the way, "convenience" and "best practices" are not the same thing - "best practice" is what will be most advantageous for your company in the long run, "convenience" is what is good just for you, and in the short run.

Answer (score 0):

[**It is usually best if the target of a rule is the name of the file the rule produces.**](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/)

So the `compile` rule:

```
compile: $(CFILE)
    $(CC) -S -combine $^ -o $(APP).s
```

should be this:

```
$(APP).s: $(CFILE)
    $(CC) -S -combine $^ -o $@
```

Likewise the object rule:

```
%: %.s compile
    $(AS) -o $@.o $<
```

should be this:

```
%.o: %.s
    $(AS) -o $@ $<
```

(There's no reason for it to depend on `compile` or `$(APP).s`, since `bubble_uart.s` is irrelevant to most object files.)

Then the list of object files should include `bubble_uart.o`:

```
SFILES = $(sort $(wildcard *.s) $(APP).s)
OFILES = $(patsubst %.s,%.o,$(SFILES))
```

(The `sort` is to remove duplicates.) Note that this is the list of object files needed for construction of the executable, *not* the list of object files that happen to exist at the beginning of the build process.

Finally, the executable:

```
$(APP): $(OFILES)
    $(LK) -o $@ -T browtb.x $^
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: @Beta just one thing, `$(APP)` should also depend on `browtb.x`.  And of course, I think, all targets with non-trivial recipes should depend on the Makefile(s) - but that is just my opinion, almost nobody does it.  When changing Makefile, people just clean and rebuild, which is silly, but that's what my users do, that's what they have always done :)